# Highcharts: browser width affects marker drawn or hidden

Tags: highcharts, markers

I have a line on a chart with a marker (icon). Highcharts is hiding the icon based on some behavior I do not know about.

The code to add 'points' to my data series ('output') looks like (I know enabledThreshold is redundant, but had to try something) this:

```
    output.push({
       id: id,
       data: points,
       keys: ['x', 'y', 'marker'],
       marker: { enabled: true, enabledThreshold: 0, },
       color: 'transparent',
       lineWidth: 1,
       animation: false,
       showInLegend: false,
       enableMouseTracking: false,
    });
```

Here is an image of the browser with the marker:
[image]

And this is what happens if I make the browser window just a little less wide:
[image]

The little red icon is gone (making the browser wider will bring it back). I want the icon there 100% of the time.

Comment: Could you reproduce this issue in an online code editor like jsfiddle?

Comment: My source code is huge and proprietary. I'm hoping someone from Highcharts would have some ideas or insights. BTW, I trigger a chart redraw on the browser resized event (cause somebody has to do it).

Comment: How many points do you have? If it's a Highstock, maybe you have dataGrouping enabled and some markers are grouped

Comment: Yes it is highstock, somehow forgot to mention that, a bit surprised it matters

Answer (score 0):

Thanks raf18seb, you nailed it. Unfortunately dataGrouping is enabled by default, so it is necessary to disabled it:

```
  dataGrouping: {
                  enabled: false,
                  forced: false // not sure this is necessary but whatever
               },
```

Generally I seem to have a lot of code over-riding highcharts default behaviors...

Comment: You're welcome. I'm sorry that you needed to disable many default options manually, but remember that there must be a rational reason(s) why it is the way it is ;)